# Is the order of elements inside a MongoDB array guaranteed to be consistent?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, serialization

In an application I'm making in Ruby, I store objects in a MongoDB database using MongoMapper.

Among other things, I need to store an array that is a property of a document:

```
{String => { [Strings] }
```

Or to put it in a more Javascript style notation:

```
{
    "fooArray" [
        "one",
        "two",
        "three"
    ]
}
```

Is the order of this array guaranteed to be preserved, or must I do something else to guarantee order?  After a few tests it **seems** to work, but I need to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array is an ordered data structure. So yes, the order should be preserved. Your tests confirm this. If the order wasn't preserved, this would be a major bug in MongoMapper.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the order of the items inside an array will stay the same.
You can read more here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html

> Arrays are ordered, integer-indexed collections of any object.